# disable babel transpile on the fly in react

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

For some reason I want to convert my function in react to string.

Like

```
toStringSpecial() {
    return ( < h1 onClick = {
            e => e
        } > hello < /h1>)
    }
    render() {
        return ({
            this.toStringSpecial.toString()
        })
    }
```

This won't work because I used babel. What I saw is a 'spoiled' output. How to exclude babel on the fly? or inline. I don't know how to call it.

I can configure webpack to exclude babel in certain directory, but I need babel, just that I want to use the toString() method to print function.

Comment: If you would disable babel for the `h1` it would result in an error, JSX != JS. Would it be an option to actually use a string, e.g. `return ('<h1 onClick={e=>e}>hello</h1>')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS JSX toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836016/reactjs-jsx-tostring)

Answer (score -1):

Please check reactjs documentation link below:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

you should follow this structure

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print the event like onClick